# cannot get xmlDoc to load any value. Keep getting null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an xml file that I retreive via terminal emulation. I want to parse the results into a textarea in html. I am able to view the file in the textarea in xml format but have been unable to parse it into lines of the inner text.

Here is the javascript/jquery:

```
var x = ""
var y = ""
var Command="";
var cmd=""
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('jquery working');

$('#tester').click(function() {
     $("#disptext").val("");
    var APOresp = new ActiveXObject("DAT32COM.TERMINALEMULATION");
    var Command = "<FORMAT>>*IA</FORMAT>";
    APOresp.MakeEntry(Command);
        //APOresp.GetMore(true,false);
    var x = APOresp.ResponseXML;
    APOresp.Close();
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(x);
    $(x).find('RESPONSE').each(function() {   //these lines do not work. I get null xmlDoc reference
    $("#disptext").val($(this).text() + "<br />");
    });
    //$("#disptext").val(xmlDoc.xml);  //disptext is the textarea
});
```

Here is what a portion of the text file looks like:

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--This is a host terminal response-->
<RESPONSE xmlns="x-schema:C:\fp\swdir\Content\emulation-schema.xml">
    <LINE INDEX="1"><![CDATA[SIGN IN ]]><CARRIAGE_RETURN/></LINE>
    <LINE INDEX="2"><SOM/></LINE>
</RESPONSE>
```

Most files are much longer.

I want to get the text for each "LINE: tag and loop it into the textarea. It does put in the whole xml file in xml format if I use the last commented out line in the javascript file. For some unknown reason, I am unable to use the xmlDoc. I keep getting errors that the xmlDoc has null values. I have been trying to fix this for a number of days without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's with the extra tags in xml that don't have matches

Comment: `<FORMAT>>*IA</FORMAT>` is not well-formed XML. You might want to check error messages that your various ActiveX object provide.

Comment: I did fix the xml file though it worked previously. I think the problem lies with the line "xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");". The xmlDoc is not being filled with any data. This really has me stumped.